# Custom hostnames on /etc/hosts not resolved

Tags: ubuntu, hosts

I've added a few hostnames in `/etc/hosts` to resolve to my LXD container:

```
$ less /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       HOST
lemh            10.0.3.219
pma.lemh        10.0.3.219
wp.lemh         10.0.3.219
```

But `ping`, `getent ahosts` or Firefox cannot resolve them. I don't want to restart right now.

I've tried `systemctl restart networking.service` to no avail. Is there a way to resolve them without restarting my system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in /etc/hosts you have to write:

```
ip alias
```

so the correct form is:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       HOST
10.0.3.219 lemh pma.lemh wp.lemh
```

Comment: You're right, and nothing needs to be restarted either. Cheers!